# Selenium test is overwritten by the second session while the parallel execution

Tags: java, selenium, cross-browser, testng, saucelabs

I need some help to figure out the problem while cross-browser selenium java test execution through the Saucelabs. I'm running one test over 2 browsers selected from the Jenkins job.

While the execution one test is passed another one (the similar) is getting failure with the error:

## 504 Gateway Time-out

. The server didn't respond in time. 
So it's unable to move into the next step.

It seems like one test interrupts another. Both tests are running under their own tunnel and thread.

```
Aug 30, 2018 7:17:44 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake 
createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
30-08-2018 07:17:49.235 [TestNG-PoolService-0] INFO  
[com.***.tests.TestBase_Local:96] - Open a site URLDriver: RemoteWebDriver: 
chrome on XP (4f5a5d685f4c44c9a5864e91cb8f11e9)
Driver: RemoteWebDriver: chrome on XP (4f5a5d685f4c44c9a5864e91cb8f11e9)
thread id:14 Timestamp :2018-08-30T07:17:49.370
30-08-2018 07:17:51.912 [TestNG-PoolService-0] INFO  
[com.**.tests.TestBase_Local:35] - Select 'No thanks' on the popup

Aug 30, 2018 7:17:53 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake 
createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
30-08-2018 07:17:58.886 [TestNG-PoolService-1] INFO  
[com.**.tests.TestBase_Local:96] - Open a site URLDriver: 
RemoteWebDriver: MicrosoftEdge on ANY (c6978c03531d408485588ba501ff0589)
Driver: RemoteWebDriver: MicrosoftEdge on ANY 
(c6978c03531d408485588ba501ff0589)
thread id:15 Timestamp :2018-08-30T07:17:58.887
30-08-2018 07:18:03.406 [TestNG-PoolService-1] INFO  
[com.**.tests.TestBase_Local:35] - Select 'No thanks' on the popup
30-08-2018 07:18:05.337 [TestNG-PoolService-1] INFO  
[com.**.tests.TestBase_Local:38] - Search by input
```

Sharing the code:

```java
public class Search extends RemoteTestBase {

    @Test(dataProvider = "browsers")
    public void SolrSearchTest(String browser, String version, String os, Method method) throws Exception {
        this.createRemoteDriver(browser, version, os, method.getName());
        System.out.println("Driver: " + driver.toString());

        Application app = new Application(driver);

        ConfigFileReader configRead = new ConfigFileReader();

        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,100);

        app.homePage().SelectNoThanks();
        Log.info("Select 'No thanks' on the popup");

        app.searchField().SearchBy(configRead.SearchInput());
        Log.info("Search by input");
    }
}
```

The extended RemoteTestBase class:

```java
public class RemoteTestBase {

    public WebDriver driver;
    private static String baseUrl;
    RandomDataSelect randomuser;
    private PropertyLoader propertyRead;
    public Logger Log = Logger.getLogger(TestBase_Local.class.getName());

    private static final String SAUCE_ACCESS_KEY = System.getenv("SAUCE_ACCESS_KEY");
    private static final String SAUCE_USERNAME = System.getenv("SAUCE_USERNAME");

    @BeforeMethod
    @DataProvider(name = "browsers", parallel = true)
    public static Object[][] sauceBrowserDataProvider(Method testMethod) throws JSONException {
        String browsersJSONArrayString  = System.getenv("SAUCE_ONDEMAND_BROWSERS");
        System.out.println(browsersJSONArrayString);
        JSONArray browsersJSONArrayObj = new JSONArray(browsersJSONArrayString);

        Object[][] browserObjArray = new Object[browsersJSONArrayObj.length()][3];
        for (int i=0; i < browsersJSONArrayObj.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject browserObj = (JSONObject)browsersJSONArrayObj.getJSONObject(i);
            browserObjArray[i] = new Object[]{ browserObj.getString("browser"), browserObj.getString("browser-version"), browserObj.getString("os")};
        }
        return browserObjArray;
    }

    void createRemoteDriver(String browser, String version, String os, String methodName) throws Exception {
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        Class<? extends RemoteTestBase> SLclass = this.getClass();
        capabilities.setCapability("browserName", browser);
        if (version != null) {
            capabilities.setCapability("browser-version", version);
        }
        capabilities.setCapability("platform", os);

        capabilities.setCapability("name", SLclass.getSimpleName());

        capabilities.setCapability("tunnelIdentifier", "***");

        driver = (new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://" + SAUCE_USERNAME + ":" + SAUCE_ACCESS_KEY + "@ondemand.saucelabs.com:80/wd/hub"), capabilities));

        randomuser = new RandomDataSelect();
        propertyRead = new PropertyLoader();
        baseUrl = propertyRead.getProperty("site.url");
        getURL();
    }

    private void getURL () {
        driver.get(baseUrl);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        this.annotate("Visiting HDSupply page..." + driver.toString());
        Log.info("Open a site URL" + "Driver: " + driver.toString());
    }

    private void printSessionId() {
        String message = String.format("SauceOnDemandSessionID=%1$s job-name=%2$s",(((RemoteWebDriver) driver).getSessionId()).toString(), "some job name");
        System.out.println(message);
    }

    @AfterMethod(description = "Throw the test execution results into saucelabs")
    public void tearDown(ITestResult result) throws Exception {
        ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("sauce:job-result=" + (result.isSuccess() ? "passed" : "failed"));
        printSessionId();
        driver.quit();
    }

    void annotate(String text) {
        ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("sauce:context=" + text);
    }
}
```

The suite.xml:

```java
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Tests Suite" verbose="4" parallel="tests" data-provider-thread-count="2">
    <test name="AllTests" parallel="methods">
        <classes>
            <class name="com.***.tests.Search"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Project info: java, selenium, testng, maven, saucelabs, jenkins

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in your test code. Its definitely related to race condition between your `@Test` methods [ you have your `parallel="true"` in your `@DataProvider` annotation and `parallel="methods" ]`

You need to refactor your code such that your `driver` object is thread safe.

Some of the ways in which you can do it is using :

- ThreadLocal variants of WebDriver.
- Create your webdriver instance and inject that as an attribute into the `ITestResult` object.

The below sample shows how to use a `ThreadLocal` variant to make your code thread-safe

```java
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import org.testng.ITestResult;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;

public class RemoteTestBase {

  public static final ThreadLocal<RemoteWebDriver> driver = new ThreadLocal<>();
  private static String baseUrl;
  private static final String SAUCE_ACCESS_KEY = System.getenv("SAUCE_ACCESS_KEY");
  private static final String SAUCE_USERNAME = System.getenv("SAUCE_USERNAME");

  void createRemoteDriver(String browser, String version, String os, String methodName)
      throws Exception {
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    Class<? extends RemoteTestBase> SLclass = this.getClass();
    capabilities.setCapability("browserName", browser);
    if (version != null) {
      capabilities.setCapability("browser-version", version);
    }
    capabilities.setCapability("platform", os);
    capabilities.setCapability("name", SLclass.getSimpleName());
    capabilities.setCapability("tunnelIdentifier", "***");

    URL url = new URL(
        "http://" +
            SAUCE_USERNAME + ":" +
            SAUCE_ACCESS_KEY + "@ondemand.saucelabs.com:80/wd/hub");

    RemoteWebDriver rwd = new RemoteWebDriver(url, capabilities);
    driver.set(rwd);
    getURL();
  }

  protected static RemoteWebDriver getDriver() {
    return driver.get();
  }

  private void getURL() {
    getDriver().get(baseUrl);
    getDriver().manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    this.annotate("Visiting HDSupply page..." + driver.toString());
  }

  private void printSessionId() {
    String message = String.format("SauceOnDemandSessionID=%1$s job-name=%2$s",
            getDriver().getSessionId(), "some job name");
    System.out.println(message);
  }

  @AfterMethod(description = "Throw the test execution results into saucelabs")
  public void tearDown(ITestResult result) {
    String txt = "sauce:job-result=" + (result.isSuccess() ? "passed" : "failed");
    getDriver().executeScript(txt);
    printSessionId();
    getDriver().quit();
  }

  void annotate(String text) {
    getDriver().executeScript("sauce:context=" + text);
  }
}
```

All your sub-classes would try to access the `RemoteWebDriver` object via `getDriver()` method.

The caveat is that your `@BeforeMethod` needs to call `createRemoteDriver()` so that the `RemoteWebDriver` object gets instantiated and pushed into the `ThreadLocal` context which will be valid and be accessible within a `@Test` method.

The rule is always `@BeforeMethod` (driver instantiation happens) > `@Test` (driver gets consumed > `@AfterMethod` (driver cleanup should happen). This is the only combo wherein a `RemoteWebDriver` object is valid within a `ThreadLocal` context.